# возвращает null (querySelectorAll)

Tags: javascript, html, css3

Есть html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>Войти в приложение</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/index.css">
 <script src="./js/index.js"></script>
</head>
<body class="register-page">

 <div class="register-auth">
    <div class="error-1"></div> 
          <div class="error-2"></div>
  <div class="register-auth-header-exit">
   <div class="register-auth-title">Войти в приложение</div>
  </div>
  <form  action="">
   <input  class="register-auth-input-error" placeholder="Заполните поле" type="text">
   
   <input  class="register-auth-input-error" placeholder="Неверный пароль" type="password">
    
   <input class="register-auth-button-exit" type="submit" value="Войти">
  </form>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

не могу обратиться к селектору js:

```js
var el = document.querySelector('.register-auth-input-error');
console.log(el);/*Возвращает null*/
```

возвращает null, а мне нужно добавить class

```js
el.classList.add("error");
```

если не трудно, направьте на путь истинный)

Comment: скрипт отрабатывает до того, как прогрузился весь dom. Надо скрипт либо в конец писать, либо window.onload

Comment: `querySelectorAll` не может возвращать null, так как возвращает коллекцию, и в случае отсутствия элементов удовлетворяющих селектору вернет пустую коллекцию

Comment: Спасибо за ответы. Попробовал написать скрипт в конец, и о чудо, все заработало!

Answer (score 1):

Все нормально работает:

```js
var el = document.querySelector('.register-auth-input-error');
console.log(el);
el.classList.add("error");
```

```css
.error {border: 1px solid red; }
```

```html
<body class="register-page">

 <div class="register-auth">
    <div class="error-1"></div> 
          <div class="error-2"></div>
  <div class="register-auth-header-exit">
   <div class="register-auth-title">Войти в приложение</div>
  </div>
  <form  action="">
   <input  class="register-auth-input-error" placeholder="Заполните поле" type="text">
   
   <input  class="register-auth-input-error" placeholder="Неверный пароль" type="password">
    
   <input class="register-auth-button-exit" type="submit" value="Войти">
  </form>
 </div>
</body>
```